# DateTime.TryParseExact() rejecting valid formats

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I'm parsing a DateTime value in an `ASP.NET WebForms` page and the date string keeps getting rejected by the `DateTime.TryParseExact()` method even though it clearly matches one of the supplied format strings.

It seems to fail on my development machine at home but work on the production server, so I am thinking of local date settings being involved, but this error occurs even when I supply an `IFormatProvider (CultureInfo)` object as a parameter

Here's the code:

```
DateTime startDate;
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy", "d/M/yyyy", "d/MM/yyyy",
                    "dd/MM/yy", "dd/M/yy", "d/M/yy", "d/MM/yy"};

var errStart = row.FindControl("errStartDate"); //my date format error message
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, formats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
{
    errStart.Visible = true; //we get here even with a string like "20/08/2012"
    return false;
}
else
{
    errStart.Visible = false;
}
```

Note I'm giving a `null FormatProvider` in the above, **but** the same problem occurs when I provide a `CultureInfo` object as
`(CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US"))` for this parameter.

What am I missing?

Comment: In US culture, date formats are m/d/y not d/m/y

Comment: Even without mentioning FormatProvider, this code seems to be working fine for me. Try specifying InvariantCulture.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Try:

```
 DateTime.TryParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, formats, 
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is the Simple method, Use ParseExact

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
DateTime result;
String dateString = "Sun 08 Jun 2013 8:30 AM -06:00";
String format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 8):

Here  you can check for couple of things.

1. Date formats you are using correctly. You can provide more than one format for `DateTime.TryParseExact`. Check the complete list of formats, available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).
2. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` which is more likely add problem. So instead of passing a `NULL` value **or** setting it to `CultureInfo provider = new CultureInfo("en-US")`, you may write it like.
   .

   ```
   if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, formats, 
                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                   System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out startDate))
   {
       //your condition fail code goes here
       return false;
   }
   else
   {
       //success code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Try C# 7.0

```
var Dob= DateTime.TryParseExact(s: YourDateString,format: "yyyyMMdd",provider: null,style: 0,out var dt)
 ? dt : DateTime.Parse("1800-01-01");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string DemoLimit = "02/28/2018";
 string pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
 CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US"); 
 DateTime.TryParseExact(DemoLimit, pattern, enUS, 
                     DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out datelimit);
```

For more https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx