# How to check datetime format in a string?

Tags: c#, datetime, format

i got a string with a datetime value so i want to validate that the value is always with this format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" how can i do that?

i have this code but it´s always throwing true.

```
  public Boolean validaFecha(string fecha)
    {
        DateTime dDate;
        Boolean resp = false;

        if (DateTime.TryParse(fecha, out dDate))
        {
            resp = true;
        }

        return resp;

    }
```

Comment: Please tell me you're not using this to check input for an sql command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [DateTime.TryParseExac](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)t method and specify the format :

```
public static Boolean validaFecha(string fecha)    
{
    DateTime dDate;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(fecha, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", 
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dDate);
}
```

Example of use :

```
bool isValid = validaFecha("2015-01-24T12:15:54"); // Will be true
```

Answer (score -1):

Use :

DateTime.TryParseExact Method (String, String, IFormatProvider)

```
[MSDN Date Time Try Parse Exact][1]
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999912/datetime-tryparseexact-rejecting-valid-formats