# DateTime.TryParseExact won't parse what appears to be a valid date string

Tags: c#, datetime

This is going to be one of those "I can't believe I didn't think of that" questions, but it's been vexing me for going on two days.

I've got bunch of date strings (and many more columns of data) coming out of a .csv file that are in this format: `8/8/2017 8:57`

I've read through the SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999912/datetime-tryparseexact-rejecting-valid-formats) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242129/c-sharp-datetime-tryparseexact-multiple-formats?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well as the documentation on MSDN from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx#Culture) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here are a couple of things I've tried in C# statements in LINQPad, adapted from the [MSDN examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string[] data = { "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09,-1.202865"};
Console.WriteLine(data);

string dateValue = "8/8/2017 8:57";
string[] patterns = {"M/d/yyyy H:mm", "MM/dd/yyyy H:mm"};

DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data[0].ToString(), patterns,
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
       out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.",
    dateValue,
    parsedDate);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.",
    dateValue);
}

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data[0].ToString(),
    patterns,
    null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
    out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.",
    dateValue, 
    parsedDate);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.",
    dateValue);
}
```

Both result in:

`Unable to convert '8/8/2017 8:57' to a date and time.`

`Unable to convert '8/8/2017 8:57' to a date and time.`

I've tried several variants in the `string[] patterns...` declaration to no avail.

What am I missing?  I suspect the problem lies in my patterns array, but maybe not?  This seems like it should be easy.

I'm not married to `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, so long as I get a valid DateTime out of the conversion.

**Edit:**  After some of the comments, I've checked my `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, and it is `en-US`, which should be fine, or at least I think so.

**Edit1:** As pointed out by most, I was using an entire string instead of the date value, although I still get an error using the single string.  Here's the first `if()` modified as suggested by Joel below:

```
string[] data = "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09,".Split(',');
string dateValue = "8/8/2017 8:57";
string[] patterns = {"M/d/yyyy H:mm"};

DateTime parsedDate;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data[0], patterns,
       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
       out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.",
    dateValue,
    parsedDate);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}' to a date and time.",
    dateValue);
}
```

I've managed to incorporate a version of this into my production code that's working as expected.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: My guess: you are using CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, but dates of types '8/8/2017' are American culture "en-US"

Comment: Just tried your code and it worked perfectly: `Converted '8/8/2017 8:57' to 08/08/2017 08:57:00.`

Comment: Executing your code in ConsoleApplication1 yields: `Converted '8/8/2017 8:57' to 08.08.2017 08:57:00.`. So it has to be something with your computer or settings...

Comment: Hmm, I thought that I should be using InvarientCulture since it was coming from a file judging from the advice on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9760237/what-does-cultureinfo-invariantculture-mean).  Do you guys have any suggestions for what I could change in my code to get what I want?  And yes I am in the US.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read your code if you would put line a line break between the condition of your `if` statement and the body - personally I'd encourage you to use braces too.

Comment: Next, I'm not surprised that the first conversion fails - the string "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09," isn't a date, because it's got all the rest of the data after it. Concentrate on converting just the valid date string.

Comment: @JonSkeet, edited per your request.  I copy and pasted from the MSDN example, I'd normally use braces as well.  Regarding your second comment, I'm using the first element of the array (data[0]), but swapping that for the string `dateValue` nets me the same error.

Comment: @delliottg `string[] data = { "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09,-1.202865"};` is a single element in the array.

Comment: You need to use `string[] data = { "8/8/2017 8:57","-1.220135","-1.239456","-3.20E-08","-4.47E-09","-1.202865"};` for multiple elements in the array.

Comment: Hah, now I see what you guys meant, the code here is a subset of my actual code which does a split on the string array on the commas, I'll edit the question appropriately, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The last comment was hidden and I didn't see it when I first wrote my answer... but I stand by my last  paragraph still.

Comment: One reason may be that the current culture uses a different date separator than `/` or a different time separator than `:`. You should escape/protected the special characters `/` and `:` if you want a literal slash or colon. For example like this: `string[] patterns = { "M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm", "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy H':'mm" };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look carefully at your data:

```
string[] data = { "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09,-1.202865"};
```

This array has only **one** element, where the value of that element is all of the text. It seems different in the console messages because you put the `8/8/2017 8:57` value into a separate variable, rather than using the array.

Did you perhaps want this instead?

```
string[] data={"8/8/2017 8:57","-1.22013","-1.239456","-3.20E-08","-4.47E-09","-1.202865"};
```

Or maybe you wanted this:

```
var data = "8/8/2017 8:57,-1.220135,-1.239456,-3.20E-08,-4.47E-09,-1.202865".Split(',');
```

<sup>**Note I don't generally condone using `.Split()` as a csv parser, but for this simple example it gets the point across.</sup>

Whatever you do, I'd make sure your Console messages accurately reflect what you tried to do (use `data[0]` as the first substitution), so you can be sure the `TryParseExact()` method is looking at the string you think it is.

Comment: I've been able to get my production code working, however, how would you recommend splitting a .csv file?  The actual data files are enormously larger than the single truncated example here (roughly a 20k rows x 33 columns per file).  If there's a better way to parse through it, I'm all ears.

Comment: Pull in a csv library from nuget. CsvHelper seems popular recently. I'm partial to EasyCSV (but I'm biased). You should get a nice performance boost as a bonus, as Split() isn't exactly fast, either.